# how does print macro work in assembly language?

Tags: linux, assembly, macros, nasm, x86-64

```
section .data
%macro print 2
mov rax ,1      ; function call
mov rdi ,1      ; device
mov rsi ,%1         ; source of data
mov rdx ,%2         ; length of data
syscall         ; system call
%endmacro
```

Comment: It calls Linux [`sys_write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) with fd=1 (stdout), and the pointer+length from the macro args.  Return value is in rax.

Answer (score 0):

The macro sets up the registers for the 64 bit calling convention with the proper values for a `sys_write()` and then executes `syscall`.

Additionally, the macro takes two arguments (`macro print 2`), which are represented by `%1` and `%2` in the code, which are moved into `RSI` and `RDX`, representing the address where the string to be printed is stored and the length of the string, respectively.